# AX Lookup problem - error code:1100 Permission Denied portName

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload videos to my firebase database but when ever i select a video in the app and the video is compressed my app gives me the following:

```
[AXRuntimeCommon] Unknown client: "AppName"
[core] "Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "(null)""
[AXRuntimeCommon] AX Lookup problem - errorCode:1100 error:Permission denied portName:'com.apple.iphone.axserver' PID:5979 ( ... )
```

I am not sure if this is to do with giving the app permission to access the media as i have done this.

This is my code that i am using to add the video to firebase:

```
func uploadVideo() {
    
    let videoPicker = UIImagePickerController()
    videoPicker.allowsEditing = true
    videoPicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
    present(videoPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
   
    if let videoUrl = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? NSURL {

        let fileName = "Videos.mov"
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(fileName)
            storageRef.putFile(from: videoUrl as URL, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            
            if error != nil {
                print("Failed upload of Video:", error)
                return
            }
            
            storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (downloadURL, error) in
                if let storageUrl = downloadURL?.absoluteString {
                    print(storageUrl)
                }
            })

        })
    }
}
```

If there a way that i can fix this?

Comment: Do you have a firewall? Have you disabled ATS? Also, is this on a device/sim?

Comment: It happens when i run the app on my own iphone 10

Comment: Have you signed into your Apple account?

Comment: Maybe won’t fix the issue, but it’s an Apple domain which seems suspicious for a Firebase issue.

Comment: Also you’ve added the permissions to access the photo library in Info.plist and you are getting the prompt, and accepted? just confirming

Comment: yes i have added it to the info.plist and i am logged into my apple id

Comment: did you fix this issue? it happens to me when I select more than 3 images

Comment: hey are you able to fix it? I am receiving the same error when dismissing photo library

Answer (score -1):

Check the ImagePickerController delegate is assigned or not

```
   let imageVC = UIImagePickerController()
   imageVC.delegate = self
```